# Attributes outside of __init__ in the presence of properties

Tags: python, properties, attributes

Pylint tells me that I set `_age` outside of `__init__` which is not good stylistically and I see why. However, if I use properties to ensure that my attributes are set within a certain interval, then it does make sense to have the attributes set in the property setter. How do I reconcile these two opposing thoughts?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, age, height, weight):
        self.age = age

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, age):
        if 18 <= age <= 81:
            self._age = age
        else:
            raise ValueError('You are either too old or too young')
```

Comment: If you are using getters/setters like that, then inside your init you should be doing `self._age = age`

Comment: `self.age = age` should be `self._age = age`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clear that the answer given by idjaw misunderstands the design of the code, skipping the exception that should be raised when he tries to set the 'age' to 1.

The pylint exception appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/409) that has just never been resolved. Your best bet would just be to use `# pylint: disable=attribute-defined-outside-init` in-line.

Answer (score 4):

You are not *really* implementing the getters/setters properly. What you should be doing in your init is actually setting `self._age = age`:

```
def __init__(self, age, height, weight):
    self._age = age
```

With that correction, now things will work as expected according to your design:

```
p = Person(1, 2, 3)
p.age = 10
```

Output:

```
ValueError: You are either too old or too young
```

Non exception:

```
p = Person(1, 20, 3)
p.age = 22
age = p.age
print(age)
```

Output: 22